# Show object in Object Browser

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any hotkey to show focused object in Object Browser?

Like <kbd>F12</kbd> but with Object Browser instead of code editor.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the context menu at "Go to Definition", the shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.